# Replace before save to CSV

Tags: scrapy

I'm using scrapy's export to CSV but sometimes the content I'm scraping contains quotes and comma's which i don't want.

How can I replace those chars with nothing '' before outputting to CSV?

Heres my CSV containing the unwanted chars in the strTitle column:

```
strTitle,strLink,strPrice,strPicture
"TOYWATCH 'Metallic Stones' Bracelet Watch, 35mm",http://shop.nordstrom.com/s/toywatch-metallic-stones-bracelet-watch-35mm/3662824?origin=category,0,http://g.nordstromimage.com/imagegallery/store/product/Medium/11/_8412991.jpg
```

Heres my code which errors on the replace line:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    titles = hxs.xpath("//div[@class='fashion-item']")
    items = []
    for titles in titles[:1]:
        item = watch2Item()
        item ["strTitle"] = titles.xpath(".//a[@class='title']/text()").extract()
        item ["strTitle"] = item ["strTitle"].replace("'", '').replace(",",'') 
        item ["strLink"] = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, titles.xpath("div[2]/a[1]/@href").extract()[0])
        item ["strPrice"] = "0"
        item ["strPicture"] = titles.xpath(".//img/@data-original").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the solution was:

```
item["strTitle"] = [titles.xpath(".//a[@class='title']/text()").extract()[0].replace("'", '').replace(",",'')]
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Try adding this line before the replace.

```
item["strTitle"] = ''.join(item["strTitle"])
```

---

```
strTitle = "TOYWATCH 'Metallic Stones' Bracelet Watch, 35mm"
strTitle = strTitle.replace("'", '').replace(",",'')  

strTitle == "TOYWATCH Metallic Stones Bracelet Watch 35mm"
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting the following error: exceptions.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Providing each instance of `item["strTitle"]` only contains a single item, then try this `item["strTitle"] = item["strTitle"][0].replace("'", '').replace(",",'')`

Comment: Thanks but i now i get:


item["strTitle"] = item["strTitle"][0].replace("'", '').replace(",",'')


exceptions.AttributeError: 'Selector' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Did you try my edit?  Try this before the replace:  item["strTitle"] = ''.join(item["strTitle"])

Comment: `item["strTitle"] = ''.join(item["strTitle"]).replace("'", '').replace(",",'')`   exceptions.TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Selector found